# Terraform aws_cognito_identity_pool : what should be the client id and provider name?

Tags: amazon-cognito, terraform

> error : "cognito_identity_providers.0.client_id must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores"

This problem is from the client_id and provider_name on the aws_cognito_identity_pool resource . Where do we get these values. Terraform is not following AWS naming. I have tried Pool id and Pool ARN. but those don't work I also tried App client id

The sample provided in documentation below is not clear

```
cognito_identity_providers {
    client_id               = "6lhlkkfbfb4q5kpp90urffae"
    provider_name           = "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_Tv0493apJ"
    server_side_token_check = false
  }
```

Answer (score 17):

It should look like this:

```
cognito_identity_providers {
  client_id               = "${aws_cognito_user_pool_client.YOURCLIENT.id}"
  provider_name           = "${aws_cognito_user_pool.YOURPOOL.endpoint}"
  server_side_token_check = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The client_id and provider_name should be provided as below,

```
cognito_identity_providers {
    client_id               = "${aws_cognito_user_pool_client.client.id}"
    provider_name           = "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${aws_cognito_user_pool.ur_pool.id}"
    server_side_token_check = true
  }
```